# How To add a Text Field to Product View

Tags: product, php, phtml

I am trying to add a text field to the product view on the front end of the site.

I appreciate this can be done through custom options but that would involve creating the option for every product that needs the text box.

Instead, I am trying to just create a text field within the template programmatically. However, I am unsure at how best to do this so that it might add itself to the database.

Any help on how to achieve this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Catalog -> Attribute and create new with options
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: **text area** (here you can write also a Default Value) 
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end: **Yes**
Of course at the end you must hook the Attribute under appropriate categories

Comment: Does this not only show what you have put within the textbox on the backend though? As opposed to showing an actual textbox on the frontend?

Comment: who should write in that text area? customer?

Comment: Yeah, It is to customise a product through writing within a textbox on the actual product view. 

An example of this could be writing in your name on the back of a t-shirt. You would need to write in what you would like through the text-box.

Comment: I think this might help you https://www.evernote.com/shard/s107/sh/dad67e41-af89-411c-90e5-76eb434009bd/5bb03df7781269b98281422aef112304

Answer (score 0):

There are some extensions which allow to create templates of custom options, which can be assigned on whole attribute sets.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=template+custom+options&pl=0